# 2-way data binding for my control

Tags: android, events, attributes, android-databinding

Let's say I have my custom view, defined as follows to for data binding support:

```
@InverseBindingMethods({@InverseBindingMethod(type = com.jaredrummler.materialspinner.MaterialSpinner.class,
        attribute = "app:selectedIndex", event = "app:selectedIndexAttrChanged", method = "getSelectedIndex")})
public class MaterialSpinner extends TextView
{
 //...............
   public Integer getSelectedIndex()
   {
       return selectedIndex;
   }

  @InverseBindingAdapter(attribute = "app:selectedIndex")
  public static Integer getSelectedIndex(MaterialSpinner spinner)
   {
       return spinner.getSelectedIndex();
   }
  //**************
```

Next I need to create event `selectedIndexArttrChanged`:

```
@BindingAdapter({"app:selectedIndexAttrChanged"})
public static void setSelectedIndexListener(MaterialSpinner view, final InverseBindingListener selectedIndexChange)
{ 
}
```

But I'm not sure how to setup event. Since it's static, I can't put `notifyPropertyChanged` there. Do you have any tips?

If I make BindingAdapter non static, my app crashes with error message:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required DataBindingComponent is null
>   in class ActivityMainBinding. A BindingAdapter in MaterialSpinner is
>   not static and requires an object to use, retrieved from the
>   DataBindingComponent. If you don't use an inflation method taking a
>   DataBindingComponent, use DataBindingUtil.setDefaultComponent or make
>   all BindingAdapter methods static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume that your `MaterialSpinner` doesn't extend `AdapterView`. If it did, you should already have two-way data binding enabled for `android:selectedItemPosition`.

One thing is that you don't need an `InverseBindingAdapter` *and* `InverseBindingMethod`. You only need one or the other. In your case, since your `InverseBindingAdapter` is really just calling the getter, you should keep the InverseBindingMethod instead (less code).

To hook up the binding listener, do something like this:

```
@BindingAdapter({"app:selectedIndexAttrChanged"})
public static void setSelectedIndexListener(MaterialSpinner view,
     final InverseBindingListener selectedIndexChange)
{
    if (selectedIndexChange == null) {
        view.setOnItemSelectedListener(null);
        return;
    }
    view.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
            selectedIndexChange.onChange();
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            mAttrChanged.onChange();
        }
    });
}
```

I recommend that you look at the source for the BindingAdapters that come with data binding. If you use Android Studio to look up `AdapterViewBindingAdapter`, for example, you'll see an implementation you can use for a template.